# How can I split part of a number always in 2 numbers

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

In solidity how can i retrieve always 2 numbers from an int?

For example in the first funcion the result is 78 and the result of the second function

```
function returnNumberTest1() public returns(uint) {
    uint256 n = 85055054;

    return n & 0xff;
}

function returnNumberTest2() public returns(uint) {
    uint256 n = 55058618935774054120265983768542913389624544203505105799354858217531716133001;

    return n & 0xff;
}
```

How can I always retrieve 2 numbers indepentende of the size of the n variable?

Comment: is not clear what you are asking, do you mean the result should have 2 digits?, that is if the result is 34789 you want the returned number to be 89?

Comment: Yes i need retrieve always 2 digits, the function is only a example, the first funcion returns 2 digits and the second function returns 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a number that's two-digits in decimal (i.e. a number between 0 and 99), you can do that via `% 100`. This returns the remainder of the number when divided by `100`.